# wrap untagged links in <a> tags with Python or Django

Tags: python, django

Using Python, how can I take a string with an unformatted link like this:

```
str = "<p>Here's some safe html with a link to somewhere: \
https://google.ca but there might also be some images <img \
src='https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Man-in-circle_icon.svg' /> \
and other linky looking things</p>"
```

And wrap it in  tags like this:

```
str = "<p>Here's some safe html with a link to somewhere: \
<a href='https://google.ca' target='_blank'>https://google.ca</a> but there might also be some images <img \
src='https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Man-in-circle_icon.svg' /> \
and other linky looking things</p>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has the [`urlize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) template filter precisely for this.

Comment: "If urlize is applied to text that already contains HTML markup, things won’t work as expected. Apply this filter only to plain text."  Sot his won't work with my example.